# jQuery plugin with multiple instances to make events act on the current item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a JavaScript/jQuery Plugin which will take a JSON array of objects and generate a **popover list item selector/picker**.  You click an item/input on the page and the popover like the image below opens with your JSON list data.

[image]

**Key Features:**

- Search filter
- Paging and items per page option
- Categories and tab panel/DIVs to organize the list items into different screens on the popover
- Clicking an item selects that item by firing a custom DOM event which you can plug into to save the selected value to a DB or do whatever you want with it.
- Makes list items from JSON array of objects
- Categories can be plucked from the same JSON data and will build separate list objects for each category

**JSON Data Format**

Right now the JSON array of objects looks like this below:

```
  var mock_data_types = [{
    "type": "first_name",
    "name": "First Name1",
    "description": "Random generated First Name",
    "example": "Jason",
    "category": "person"
  }, {
    "type": "address",
    "name": "address2",
    "description": "Random generated Last Name",
    "example": "Davis",
    "category": "address"
  }, {
    "type": "domain",
    "name": "Domain Name3",
    "description": "Random generated WWW Domain Name",
    "example": "google.com",
    "category": "it"
  }];
```

---

**Current Problems**

**1)**
When there are multiple popover pickers on the page, when you select a  item it updates that selected value for all the input fields that have the popover instead of only the current open one.

I believe the code needs to maybe keep track of multiple instances

I have tried to do this but keep failing.  Can anyone hep with this issue?

---

**2)**
The complete code base is crap and can be improved as I am a PHP developer and learning JS still!

---

**Demo JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/9fpc3LLo/

Comment: The plugin receives all the elements you ran the plugin on as `$(this)`. You should loop over the elements, and you can use `.data()` to associate information with each element.

Comment: Problem 2 should be addressed at CodeReview.stackexchange.com once you get the basic functionality working.

Answer (score 0):

Great job with your plugin.

So, perhaps you could use it as a jQuery-UI (plugin) widget. You can get the docs [here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/) to use the jQuery-UI widgetFactory. I think this can help you with your first problem and give you some tips to improve the second one...

Hope that can help you.

Regards!